# Flashback + Kess, Dissident Mage

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is it possible to cast a card twice, first with Flashback AND then with [Kess, Dissident Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKess%2c%20Dissident%20Mage%5d) "play from graveyard" ability or vice versa?

Flashback says - You may play this card from your graveyard for the Flashback cost. Then remove it from the game.

Kess say - you may cast instance or sorcery card from your graveyard. If it would go into the graveyard, exile it instead.

Comment: @ikegami yeh that's what i mean, fixed the wording, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, for the same reason that you can't cast a card from your hand twice. As part of casting a spell, you place the card being cast on the stack. The card would no longer be in the graveyard to be cast.

> 601.2. [...] To cast a spell, a player follows the steps listed below, in order. [...]
>
> 601.2a [...] a player first moves that card (or that copy of a card) from where it is to the stack. [...]